# How can I control odeint to stop integration when the result reach a threshold?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, scipy

Here is my code.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint

#Constant
R0=1.475
gamma=2.
ScaleMeVfm3toEskm3 = 8.92*np.power(10.,-7.)

def EOSe(p):
    return np.power((p/450.785),(1./gamma))

def M(m,r):
    return (4./3.)*np.pi*np.power(r,3.)*p

# function that returns dz/dt
def model(z,r):
    p, m = z
    dpdr = -((R0*EOSe(p)*m)/(np.power(r,2.)))*(1+(p/EOSe(p)))*(1+((4*math.pi*(np.power(r,3))*p)/(m)))*((1-((2*R0)*m)/(r))**(-1.))
    dmdr = 4.*math.pi*(r**2.)*EOSe(p)
    dzdr = [dpdr,dmdr]
    return dzdr

# initial condition
r0=10.**-12.
p0=10**-6.
z0 = [p0, M(r0, p0)]

# radius
r = np.linspace(r0, 15, 100000)

# solve ODE
z = odeint(model,z0,r)
```

The result of `z[:,0]` keeps decreasing as I expected. But what I want is only positive values. One may run the code and try `print(z[69306])` and it will show `[2.89636405e-11 5.46983202e-01]`. That is the last point I want the `odeint` to stop integration.

Of course, the provided code shows

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power
  return np.power((p/450.785),(1./gamma))
```

because the result of p starts being negative. For any further points, the `odeint` yields the result `[nan nan]`.

However, I could use np.nanmin() to find the minimum of z[:,0] that is not `nan`. But I have a set of `p0` values for my work. I will need to call `odeint` in a loop like

```
P=np.linspace(10**-8.,10**-2.,10000)
for p0 in P:
#the code for solving ode provided above.
```

which takes more time.

I think it would reduce a time for execution if I can just stop at before z[:,0] going to be negative a value?

Comment: using [`solve_ivp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html#scipy.integrate.solve_ivp) an event function could be provided in order to terminate the integration. What is the value of `M(r0, p0)`?

Comment: @xdze2 Sorry. I've just add the M(r,p) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the modified code using `solve_ivp`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

# Constants
R0 = 1.475
gamma = 2.

def EOSe(p):
    return np.power(np.abs(p)/450.785, 1./gamma)

def M(m, r):
    return (4./3.)*np.pi*np.power(r,3.)*p

# function that returns dz/dt
# note: the argument order is reversed compared to `odeint`
def model(r, z):
    p, m = z
    dpdr = -R0*EOSe(p)*m/r**2*(1 + p/EOSe(p))*(1 + 4*np.pi*r**3*p/m)*(1 - 2*R0*m/r)**(-1)
    dmdr = 4*np.pi * r**2 * EOSe(p)
    dzdr = [dpdr, dmdr]
    return dzdr

# initial condition
r0 = 1e-3
r_max = 50
p0 = 1e-6
z0 = [p0, M(r0, p0)]

# Define the event function
# from the doc: "The solver will find an accurate value
# of t at which event(t, y(t)) = 0 using a root-finding algorithm. "
def stop_condition(r, z):
    return z[0]

stop_condition.terminal = True

# solve ODE
r_span = (r0, r_max)
sol = solve_ivp(model, r_span, z0,
                events=stop_condition)


print(sol.message)
print('last p, m = ', sol.y[:, -1], 'for r_event=', sol.t_events[0][0])

r_sol = sol.t
p_sol = sol.y[0, :]
m_sol = sol.y[1, :]

# Graph
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1);
plt.plot(r_sol, p_sol, '.-b')
plt.xlabel('r'); plt.ylabel('p');

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2);
plt.plot(r_sol, m_sol, '.-r')
plt.xlabel('r'); plt.ylabel('m');
```

Actually, using events in this case do not prevent a warning because of negative `p`. The reason is that the solver is going to evaluate the model for `p<O` anyway. A solution is to take the absolute value of  `p` in the square root (as in the code above). Using `np.sign(p)*np.power(np.abs(p)/450.785, 1./gamma)` gives interesting result too.

Comment: Thank you. The code works fine. As you said, the solver is going to evaluate the model for p<0 anyway. So, this does not make it runs with less time? Do I understand correctly?

Comment: @PanithiNakkhruea it will not really reduce the computation time, but it will directly output the "exact" final time (`sol.t_events`) and final solution, i.e. when p = 0, so it may be convenient to use the events functionality in your case...